# Interop Excel .Find() whole match not finding value, partial match does

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

So I've got a spreadsheet where I'm trying to find the index of certain column headers.
What I've found is `XlLookAt.xlWhole` does not find the value. However, if I use `XlLookAt.xlPart`it does.

I cannot use `xlPart` as it does not find the correct match in some instances.

I have confirmed that only `AMT_ISSUED` is in the cell in the actual spreadsheet and there aren't any white spaces on either end.

Does anyone know why `XlLookAt.xlWhole` doesn't work . Here's the code I'm using

```
List<int> columnNumbers = new List<int>();
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
var columnIndex = range.EntireRow.Find("AMT_ISSUED",
                            misValue, XlFindLookIn.xlValues, XlLookAt.xlWhole,
                            XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
                            false);

var index = columnIndex?.Column ?? 0;
columnNumbers.Add(index);
```

UPDATE:

I have even done this:

```
 var value = ((Range)range.Cells[1, 4]).Value2.ToString();

 var columnIndex = range.EntireRow.Find(value,
                        misValue, XlFindLookIn.xlValues, XlLookAt.xlWhole,
                        XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
                        false);
 var index = columnIndex?.Column ?? 0;
 columnNumbers.Add(index);
```

`value` has found the correct text but column index is still `null`.

WORKAROUND (I don't like it but it will get me past this hurdle)
Note: the headings could be in row 1 or 2, if it is in row 2 then row one has the first cell populated

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (var h = 1; h <= colCount; h++)
                {
                    object cellValue = ((Range)range.Cells[i, h]).Value2;
                    if ((h== 1 || h==2) && cellValue == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (columns.Contains(cellValue))
                    {
                        columnNumbers.Add(h);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking...

Comment: What is `misValue` here? Also, you may consider just adding your columns to a dictionary instead of using find.

Comment: @user1274820 I guess it's *missing value* (i.e. `Type.Missing`)

Comment: What you're looking for and what values do you have?

Comment: @JohnyL I have included that in my question above, I did have that in my code though

Comment: @JohnyL I'm looking for that cell value `AMT_ISSUED`.

Comment: `Find` returns `Range` object. You should call `.Column` property on that `Range`.

Comment: @JohnyL I do, however is that returned range is `null` it returns a null ref exception. But i'll include it in the question too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205738/discussion-between-johnyl-and-marwaha-ks).

Comment: @JohnyL Do you want to answer the question within the answers, and I'll award you the answer?

Comment: @marwaha.ks Have posted the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method returns `Range` object. So, first, you need to obtain the `Range` and then, if it's not `null`, retrieve column index:

```
// Create Excel instance
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application { Visible = true };
Excel.Workbook book = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"PATH_TO_FILE");
Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.Sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
// Search in the first row
Excel.Range header = sheet.Range["1:1"].Find("AMT_ISSUED", LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole);
if (header != null)
{
    // Header is found
    int index = header.Column;
}
else
{
    // Header is not found
}
```